# Create invoker of SSIS job sourced from queue (database table)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, .net-3.5

Preface: I'm a DBA who knows some C#, but is nowhere near an expert at it. I've been tasked with taking creating an invoker of SSIS jobs, sourced from a queue in a database table. The idea is that I take the top X (a dynamic value at job runtime, sourced from a database table) unstarted tasks and run them in parallel. It is required that the tasks be run parallel to each other. While it's easy to run a package from a package in SSIS, I don't believe there's a way (after much looking) to run them in parallel like this.

How I've decided to approach this is by creating a SSIS job to act as the invoker. It gathers the tasks to run (with their details and parameters), then uses a script task to call a C# assembly, SsisHelper (also written by me), which uses BackgroundWorkers to run the tasks in parallel. That all works fine now.

It was recently made known to me that this approach does not entirely satisfy the requirements, however. If the first (X - 1) tasks finish in one minute, but the last task takes an hour to run, we do not want to wait for this before replenishing the other slots in the queue with new tasks. But, we don't necessarily want to run the entire invoker task asynchronously (at least not in its current state), as we could potentially end up with (X + 1) tasks running, which would be equally as bad.

My thought on how to approach this was to make the call to SsisHelper asynchronous, but beforehand, try to see if the assembly is still active (i.e., it's still waiting for those one or two last jobs to finish), and then re-use it. Then, inside SsisHelper, I'd have a static count of running tasks to ensure that it never went over X. While the second part seems easy, I have no idea if it's even possible to co-opt a running .NET process like this. I'm definitely open to alternatives, but I can't change that the queue needs to be managed from SSIS initially.

Edit - this must be done in .NET 3.5.

Comment: What make you so sure you can do X task in parallel faster than you can run them serial? The database has fixed cpu, memory, and disk heads.   If one task is using cpu while the other is using cpu then yes in theory you get some true parallel processing.  In really most of the time it is disk contention and faster just to let it focus.

Comment: The tasks must be run in parallel.

Comment: To restate: you have a queue. You want to spin up N instances of SSIS and each one takes an item from the queue. Queue item determines what package runs. Yeah?

Comment: Have you seen the [reference architecture](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537533%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) on how the SSIS team loaded 1 Tb in 30 minutes?

Comment: This is not just about speed. I know for a fact that there could be a task that takes 10 minutes to run. I cannot have a completely unrelated task waiting to run while the first one is trying to finish. The tasks must be able to be run in parallel.

Comment: Clearing a queue has everything to do with speed.  A task my be functionally unrelated but it is related in that it is contending for the same resources.  Have you establish that in fact you can process in parallel faster?  An easy  task at the end of the queue only gets run as soon as it can get to the end of the queue.

Comment: Again, the tasks MUST be run in parallel. Some of these tasks aren't even SSIS jobs - they call WCF services. Most of the tasks interact with completely different tables (and, subsequently different filegroups) than the others. Trust me, I've tried to fight this, but it is out of my hands. It is a client requirement. We must be able to run tasks in parallel, regardless of whether or not the overall process is faster running them serially.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I understand your problem, there's no need for complex higgery jiggery with C# and multithreading.

I assume your queue has concepts like

```
Task | Start Time | Finish Time | Uniqueifier
SSIS |            |             | 1
WCF  |            |             | 10000000
```

Consider this SSIS package. It is the invoker.

[image]

When you launch this package, you indicate how many active items from the queue you want running. Depending on version of SSIS, it would either be a `/SET` or a package Parameter.

The first step is to see if there is any work in the queue. Initialize some SSIS Variable to indicate yes, there is work to be done.

This leads to a For Loop, not a Foreach Loop. The For Loop is going to cycle until the Variable indicates there is no work to be done.

Within our For Loop, we query our queue to see how many active processes are running. Basically, count how many have start times without end times. If that count is less than our target number of threads, we take the left path. If it's greater or equal, then we take the right path.

### Left path

The left path addresses the concept of starting a new thing. The first step there is to get an item from the queue. This should provide you with enough information about what task you need to do and a task id so you can pass that reference to the actual worker. As part of getting this reference, I'd mark the process as under way (start time = current timestamp). Perhaps you'd rather offload that to when the process truly begins. That's a design decision that depends on your specific needs.

The second step in the left path is to actually run the thing. I have a placeholder of an Execute Process Task. Maybe that's not the right thing here. Maybe you need a Script Task. It doesn't really matter, the concept is that you need to launch an asynchronous process. There are more ways to address the specifics of running an ansyc process than SO answers will allow. The crucial thing is that you pass along the reference to the task so that when the subprocess completes, it marks the task as complete (here by setting the Finish Time).

### Right path

This is just a sleep task. It spins up when all of our queues are active. Sleep for 1 second, sleep for a minute, sleep for an hour. It entirely depends on your estimated time frame. You want to minimize the observer effect without degrading the response time for processing the next queue item.

### Work task

This would be your worker tasks. Implemented as a child SSIS package but I don't really care what it is. It simply needs to

1. Do task
2. Report to the queue that it has completed its task

[image]

Comment: This looks promising. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use a BlockingCollection with a boundedCapacity

Paralled filegroups does not help if the are on the same write head.

Comment: BlockingCollections are .NET 4.0+, right? Unfortunately, I must use 3.5.

Comment: I'm sorry. Next time, I'll only post questions with easy answers.

Comment: Easy answer and complete question are not the same.  My easy answer is only invalid because the question was not complete.  You have 7 questions without a single accepted answer.   You seem to get nothing but bad answers.

Comment: Ah, well your reply was not specific about your gripe.